# How to display Data from php file after HTML Form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have my HTML form. I need that after I click on "Submit" button (validation), it has to display information containing in the **action_page_post.php** file.

Please how do i do that? Do I need to include something in this file?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("First Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["sname"].value;
    if (y == "") {
        alert("Surname must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
Surname: &nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="sname">
<br><br>
&nbsp
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in your action_page_post.php?

Comment: post your php. If there is none, the question is too broad. It is expected from you to try something first. http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: I tried nothing. I searched on Google and I got confused that's why I'm asking on a forum. Please can you tell me what to do. In my action_page_post.php there's only ( echo " ...am Practicing PHP"; )

Comment: I just wanna know, Do I need to include something in my HTML form? as Logically, how does my HTML file know where my php file is?  That's all I need to know

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need anything else here. By default, whatever is being returned (`echo`) from the PHP will be rendered as the new DOM.

just check that the returned (`echo`) code is correct.

You could check: [HTML `form` method Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_method.asp) and [GET vs POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Thanks everybody. It's solved !!!  I read somewhere while searching on Google that I have to include "myphpfilename.php" on top of the html file, that's what was confusing me. and there's a ( slash ) before my php name, when I just removed it, it's automatically worked !!!  `<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">`

Comment: So the problem was the route to the file on the server... Great, good look.

Answer (score 0):

Your html form is fine, the html page will know where your php file is through the action attribute in the form.

In your action_page_post.php file add the following code

```
<?php

//get the form inputs using php global variable post
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$surname = $_POST['sname'];

//then echo out the data or manipulate it in whatever way you wish

echo $firstname . "<br/>";
echo $surname;

?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may write `action_page_post.php` as follows.

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$sname = $_POST['sname'];

echo "First name: $fname.\n";
echo "Surname: $sname.\n";
if ($fname != $sname) {
    echo "The name you typed do not match!";
}
?>
```